# Zoho API v2 login issue

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, zoho

We use the Zoho OAuth API's response to authenticate users in our app (RoloCRM). Our approach works for most of the accounts but is failing for a few users.
We have listed the steps below, with the APIs used in our app during login.

**Step1**: We use v2 of the Zoho OAuth API for login and get basic details.
https://www.zohoapis.com/oauth/v2/auth?scope=ZohoCRM.users.ALL,ZohoCRM.org.ALL,ZohoCRM.modules.ALL,ZohoCRM.settings.ALL&client_id=&&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=

**Step2**: Once we get the access & refresh token, we call below api to get currently signed in user's email and zoho-user-id.
https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/users?type=CurrentUser

**Step3**: We call below api to get currently logged in user's organization id.
https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/org

In step2, we receive currently logged in user's zoho-user-id. We expect this to be same across different zoho teams.

**Is this assumption valid?**

**Example**:
In one of our example, same user has 2 registered zoho organizations with 2 different email ids(Email1 and Email2).

1. User validated email1 with zoho, in step2 we get "zohouserid1" and
   in step3 we get "zohoorgid1"
2. User validated email2 with zoho, in
   step2 we get "zohouserid1" and in step3 we get "zohoorgid1"

We are getting same zohouserid and organization id for two different emails (belongs to same user).

Is it possible to get actual organization id and user id based on the logged in user's email?

Answer (score 0):

It's a possibility you are not using the correct client_id for respective email-ids,make sure that when you use client_id for part(a) you must use the same client_id (for the give email-id you are using) in part(b) also.

(a) **For dwest898@test.com** : The client_id for this email-id in both code's should be same

```
echo "<a href='https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/auth?scope=ZohoSign.account.CREATE,ZohoSign.account.READ,ZohoSign.account.UPDATE,ZohoSign.documents.all,ZohoCRM.modules.ALL,WorkDrive.team.ALL,WorkDrive.workspace.ALL,WorkDrive.files.ALL&client_id=1000.NZAGLITT9FLS31433JQ23&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://localhost/zoho_leads/testaccesstoken.php'>Link</a>";
```

(b) **For dwest898@test.com**

```
 $client_id = "1000.NZAGLITT9FLS31433JQ23";
 $client_secret = "a94365a4a0ad7f64b039709b916b73a";
```

(a) **For adev4314@test.com**  : The client_id for this email-id in both code's should be same

```
echo "<a href='https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/auth?scope=ZohoCRM.modules.ALL,WorkDrive.team.ALL,WorkDrive.workspace.ALL,WorkDrive.files.ALL&client_id=1000.RORGERNX224MJSQHA5QF7Q&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://localhost/zoho_leads/testaccesstoken.php'>Link</a>";
```

(b) **For adev4314@test.com**

```
 $client_id = "1000.RORGERNX224MJSQHA5QF7Q";
 $client_secret = "8eaa1d5c89b588567490fc95f33ca15";
```